# Summary of Results Based on Members of File

Tags: excel-2010

I am not quite sure how to word this so I've also included some poorly formatted example :)  Basically I have a report exported from Cognos.  The report contains a list of cases and the people that are associated to those cases, along with additional information about their First Language and Religion (as an example).  What I would like to do is create a summary and/or chart of the results based on the unique case.

Any ideas?  Example data below:

Case Reference - Name - First Language - Religion

1. 1234 - Name1 - English - Catholic
2. 1234 - Name2 - French - Protestant
3. 4321 - Name3 - Tamil - Unknown
4. 3345 - Name4 - English - Hindu

So for a summary I'd like to see that for languages there is 1 for Tamil and 1 for French (English would be the default if no other languages are present - so for file 1234 it would have been English if there was no French speaking person).  For religions I'd like to be able to see that out of the 3 files, 1 is unknown, 1 is Hindu and also that the 3rd file is actually 2 religions (Catholic and Protestant).

I am not sure if any of this is making sense but hopefully one of you can shed some light on a possible solution.  I'd like to template it out so that on line one of the case it would have an x under each heading, but do it automatically instead of manually.  Basically, for each unique case are there any members that are French, any that are Tamil, any that are Catholic, any that are Christian, etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm following correctly. It seems you want to show for each language, how many cases they are associated with and for every case, how many religions are associated with it.

For language, add a column to your report's query called *Language Count* with the following expression:

```
count(distinct [Case Reference] for [First Language])
```

This will count the number of unique cases for each language.

For religions, add a column to your report's query called *Religion Count* with the following expression:

```
count(distinct [Religion] for [Case Reference])
```

This will count the number of unique religions for each case.